# How to Set SetOnClickListener for a button in a fragment of NavigationDrawerActivity? in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello everyone I made a Drawer Activity but in my fragment i want a button So that when i press button this Should change text to Hi or Hello, but i don't where the code should be present when i try to add code in FirstFragemt.kt file it throw an error ,Please Help me Thank you

Here is My MainActivity :

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),FirstFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,SecondFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show()
    }

    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
    drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> return true
        else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.first_activity -> {
            title = "Fragment One"
            val fragment = FirstFragment()
            val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentID, fragment, "FragmentOne")  //create first framelayout with id fram in the activity where fragments will be displayed
            fragmentTransaction.commit() // Handle the camera action
        }
        R.id.second_activity -> {
            title = "Fragment Second"
            val fragment = SecondFragment()
            val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentID, fragment, "FragmentSecond")  //create first framelayout with id fram in the activity where fragments will be displayed
            fragmentTransaction.commit()
        }

        R.id.nav_share -> {

        }
        R.id.nav_exit -> {
            System.exit(0)
        }
    }

    drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
    return true
}

 override fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri) {
     TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
 } }
```

Here is My FirstFragent file :

`

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
private var mParam1: String? = null
private var mParam2: String? = null

private var mListener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    if (arguments != null) {
        mParam1 = arguments.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
        mParam2 = arguments.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
    }



}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
fun onButtonPressed(uri: Uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener!!.onFragmentInteraction(uri)
    }
}

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = context
    } else {
        throw RuntimeException(context!!.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener")
    }
}

override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    mListener = null
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 *
 *
 * See the Android Training lesson [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) for more information.
 */
interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    fun onFragmentInteraction(uri: Uri)
}

companion object {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
    private val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FirstFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String): FirstFragment {
        val fragment = FirstFragment()
        val args = Bundle()
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
        fragment.arguments = args
        return fragment
    }
}
```

}// Required empty public constructor

Here is my FirstFragment layout xml file :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.a3.aakap.ftrial.FirstFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:text="Click me !!"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: What error is thrown?

Comment: This is error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: When i add this `override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (arguments != null) {
            mParam1 = arguments.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            mParam2 = arguments.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }

        button.setOnClickListener {
            text.setText("Hi")
        }

    }`

Comment: When i add this  `button.setOnClickListener { text.setText("Hi")` in code

Comment: are you adding that into the activity or the fragment? if inside the fragment you need a reference to your view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a overide of onViewCreated in those Fragment Here is a code :

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    button.setOnClickListener{
        text.setText("Hello")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, what you're missing is getting hold on the view of your fragment, and the views inside it (mainly your button and your TextView), and doing stuff on them.

In your FirstFragment.kt :

```
private lateinit var mTextView: TextView
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    mTextView = findViewById(R.id.text)
    findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener { mTextView.text = "Hi" }
    return view
}
```

Comment: but i was just missing a override of onViewCreated as I have on created a view

Comment: No, you already had the function in your Fragment, you were just not doing what's necessary in it

Answer (score 0):

```js
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    private var ctx: Context? = null
    private var self: View? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                              container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        ctx = container?.context
        self = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.fragment_start, container, false)
        val bDaButton = self?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.bDaButton)
        bDaButton?.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "button works!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        return self
    }
}
```

```html
<Button
        android:id="@+id/bDaButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Work!"/>
```